# MacOS Postgres 10 can't read csv file

Tags: postgresql, macos

I'm trying to copy a CSV file into a table by running a simple \copy command in Postgres;

```
postgres-# \copy solved_at FROM '/Users/funnychef/Downloads/export.csv' DELIMITER AS ',';
```

Every time I run the command I receive the Permission Denied error:

```
/Users/funnychef/Downloads/export.csv: Permission denied
```

The permissions on the file are wide open;

```
$ ls -ltr ~/Downloads/expor.csv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 funnychef  staff  145524 Jul  8 22:15 /Users/funnychef/Downloads/export.csv
```

I assumed that the issue was related to the _postgres user not having access to the file so I made that user the owner of the file but still receive the error.

```
$ ls -ltr ~/Downloads/expor.csv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 _postgres  staff  145524 Jul  8 22:15 /Users/funnychef/Downloads/export.csv
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you also checked directory permissions for `Downloads` or other parent directories? Also, try doing a `cd` to the downloads folder and then connect to psql, use only file name in copy

Comment: copy your file to /tmp and try. If it works I'll add that as an answer.

Comment: moving the file to /tmp corrected the issue.

Comment: @FunnyChef glad that it worked. Accept and upvote since it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Copy your file to `/tmp` directory  and read the csv. The normal settings for `/tmp` are 1777, which `ls` shows as `drwxrwxrwt`

Comment: I like the idea of using /tmp as an easy work-around when doing one-time loads or dumps, instead of playing with all sort of other user (database or system) or directory permissions, that may not be desirable to keep anyway.